# Include New Edits in the 'New Answers Posted' Banner?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I dig the 'New Answers Posted' banner, as it helps me review what other answers have said and I can stop before I submit something redundant.  I think it would be useful if recent edits were included in that feature.

There are times when I feel that a point is being made, but that an important facet could be highlighted and explored a bit further.  Granted, sometimes commenting to the author of an answer to prod them on with their explanation is the right approach, but sometimes it is an itch that I feel the need to scratch.

However, if in mid-post I see the banner indicating new answers, I take a moment and check if I am repeating someone else.  Unfortunately, if someone has gone in and edited their post, I will not know.  I would like to have the chance to review edits at these intervals as well.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I think that any changes should be reflected in that. Edits, Comments, and of course Answers. The idea is to tell you that something has changed since you last saw the page. It should probably also have the bar on the Edit pages.